# Generate random numbers from a normal distribution

Tags: python, database

I couldn't create normal distribution with Python. I tried this but not worked exactly.

```
def prove_nd(num,mean=3,std_dev=1.25):    
  n= np.random.normal(mean,std_dev,num)

  print(n)

prove_nd(3)
```

image:
[image]

Comment: Could you define "not worked exactly"? In what why did it give a different result than you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your code runs without any problems, maybe you forgot to write `import numpy as np`?

```
import numpy as np

def prove_nd(num, mean=3, std_dev=1.25):
    n = np.random.normal((mean, std_dev, num))
    print(n)

prove_nd(3)
```

The above code gives this output:

```
[4.22306108 2.31908355 3.39390751]
```

Comment: yes I can run this code but I want to answer this guestion "Calculate the percentage of data falling within the ranges of one standard deviation, two standard deviations, and three standard deviations of the normal distribution with a loop structure? "

Comment: So why don't you write your loop structure and calculate that? What have you tried so far? Did it work? No? What did not work? Do not expect Stack Overflow to solve your homework for you. If you try something, and you get into trouble, then you can come here and ask. Second, why did you use the `database` tag? And third, you should not upload images that contain text, rather type the text in so that it can be seen by the search engines.